# Can you delay bufferedReaders so they do not work until a specified time?

Tags: java

So, I am working on a basic math game, and I have a question related to bufferedReaders. During the first part of the application, the output displays some introductory messages showing how the game works. After that the game starts.

My only problem is that during the introductoryMessage() method, which comes before the startGame() method obviously, is that the user can input and submit items while it is still in the intro phase, possibly messing up the game. Is it possible to delay a bufferedReader so that it will only run when the startGame() method is run? Here is some code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class mainMathClass {

  public static void introductoryMessages() throws InterruptedException {


    System.out.println("Hello! This is an output based addition game.");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("\nThe rules are simple. I will ask a math" +
      "\nquestion, and you will input the answer" +
      "\nunderneath the most recent question.");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

    System.out.println("\nHere is an example:");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("\nWhat is 10/5?");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("2");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("\nIt is as simple as that. Each correct answer is " +
      "worth +1 point. Incorrect answers are worth -1 " +
      "points");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    System.out.println("Here is question 1:");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
  }

  public static void startGame() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Global variables. Do not move.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    int correctAnswerCount = 0;
    int points = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      /*The following variables must be declared in
       * in the for loop. If they are not, they cannot
       * change, meaning the for loop will not work
       * properly.
       */
      Random r = new Random();
      int low = 1;
      int high = 20;
      int a = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
      int b = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
      int problemAnswer = (a + b);
      /*Change the math symbol in problemAnswer
       *to change the way the game is played.
       *Be sure to change the string "+" to whatever
       *symbol you replaced the plus symbol with in problemAnswer
       */

      String aToString = Integer.toString(a);
      String bToString = Integer.toString(b);

      //Questions start here
      System.out.println("What is " + aToString + " + " + bToString + "?");

      userInput = br.readLine();
      int userInputToString = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

      //Check if userInputToString is equal to the math questions answer.
      //Display a certain message depending on if the users answer is correct.
      if (userInputToString == problemAnswer) { //Beginning of if-statement #1

        System.out.println("\nYou said " + userInputToString + ". That is correct!" +
          "\nYou earned 1 point!");
        points++;
        correctAnswerCount++;

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        System.out.println();

      } else {
        System.out.println("\nYou said " + userInputToString + ". That is incorrect." +
          "\nYou lost one point. :(");
        points--;

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        System.out.println();
      }

    }

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    System.out.println("You have " + correctAnswerCount + " questions answered correctly.");

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    System.out.println("\nYou have " + points + " points.");

  } //End of initializeProblem() method


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  }
}
```

Also, I have been looking up how to make an application only take numbers as input, and display an error when the input is not an integer, and move on. A lot of them involve a try-catch block, I just do not know where to put it. If someone could help me with that while they are here, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just call the `startGame()` at the end of the introductory method? That way once the introductory method has completed, it will now call the `startGame()` method. I assume this game doesn't care about executing other things in the background? As in, this is only a single threaded application that cares only about processing forward in terms of logical code execution.

Comment: No, of course there isn't a way to delay a `BufferedReader`. I've been using it for 22 years and this is the first time I've even seen such a question. People don't build in arbitrary features into software.

Comment: Just create a conditional surrounding when the reader should be allowed to be in use. Boolean readerUseable = false. Once the game starts, readerUseable = true. And then simply surround any code that requires the reader's use with an if(readerUseable)